# Automatic logout from the application if inactivity for 10 mins (Session Management )

Tags: android

I want to implement session management in android application. Where I want to logout from the application if there is an inactivity for 15 or 10mins. Currently I am using below code for session management. Its working fine if the timeout is less then 2 mins. Is there any better or alternative solution then this ?

```
public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 600000;// 15 min

    private Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        }
    };

    private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Perform any required operation for log out

            Intent intent = new Intent(AttendanceActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    public void resetDisconnectTimer() {
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
        disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    public void stopDisconnectTimer() {
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopDisconnectTimer();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by in-activity you mean that the app is not in foreground and not being used by the user.
There are better ways to go about this.
1. Save the time when the app goes to background(you can use activity lifecycle callbacks for that refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) on app open check the current time and last seen time and logout.

2. Set an alarm for the current time + x mins and silents logout the and set some flag in shared-preference. Based on the flag inflate the login screen

Comment: I want it to be like a bank application. Even if the application is in foreground but if inactive. It should logout the user

Comment: Then alarm would be a better approach for foreground cases

Comment: How to check inactivity while in foreground ?

Comment: That should be your own business logic based on the requirement. I am not sure what you mean by inactivity in foreground. If the app is in foreground then most likely user would be doing some action or reading/viewing some content on the app which i don't consider as in-active